# String values are not displaying on graph created using matplotlib-python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

I have created sample graph using matplotlib-python with below code.

```
df =pd.DataFrame ({'City': ['London', 'Jakarta', 'Newyork', 'Mumbai'],
                   'Staff': [1000,2000,3000,400]})
print (df.head())
df.plot(kind='line',x='City', y='Staff', color= 'Blue')
plt.show()
```

I am facing issue with the display of names when it is a ***line kind*** graph.
Below are the images where it shows names of the city in ***bar graph*** but not displaying in line type graph.

How do I make the city names show as labels for the X axis in the line plot?

matplotlib version used is : 3.1.3

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem (matplotlib v3.1.1, but this is likely a pandas issue, not a matplotlib one)

However, the following should explicitly set the xlabels as you desire

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame ({'City': ['London', 'Jakarta', 'Newyork', 'Mumbai'],
                    'Staff': [1000,2000,3000,400]})
ax = df.plot(kind='line',x='City', y='Staff', color= 'Blue')

# Set axis labels as desired
ax.set_xticklabels(df['City'])
ax.set_xticks(df.index)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Ralph ! that worked for me. Well why it is needed as there is no issue with bar kind graph?

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer if it helped you. I'm not entirely sure why it's needed for the line graph and not for the bar. I suspect its a bug in pandas!